# UI-grid data is not updating

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am using ui-grid in my project, for ui-grid configurations i am setting grid data, like below:

```
$scope.gridOptions ={

  data : $scope.data,
  columnDef:$scope.couumnDefs

};
```

I am making service call here and i am getting grid from DB,

```
myService.getData().then(function(data) {
                        var status = data.status;
                        if (status == 0) // success
                        {
                            $scope.data= data.gridData;
                           $scope.columnDef= data.gridCoulmunDef;
                        }
                    }, function(errorMessage) {
                        $scope.error = errorMessage;
                    });
```

But grid data is not updating, and i want to do some modification in $scope.data, but it is not updating, but here is missing the main concept of angular two way data binding

can any one suggest the what i need to do or i made any wrong please.

Thanks in advance !!!!

Comment: when and how you are calling `getData()` method ?

Comment: after  $scope.gridOptions configurations next line itself @Viplock

Comment: try using `$scope.gridOptions.data=data.gridData` on place of `$scope.data= data.gridData`

Comment: I am tried it is working fine, but after that i modified the `$scope.data` like for loop or something it is not updating again like, add new object to `$scope.data`  or delete the one object from `$scope.data`, it is not updating @Viplock

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had to solve this in a couple of different projects, and this method works for me:

> ```
>   Restangular.all("block_sets/"+<%= params[:id] %> + "/addblock").customPOST(postParams
>             ).then(function (data) {
>                 $scope.gridOptions.data = _.map(data.array, function (d) {
>                     return {
>                         exampleheader:   d.exampledata,
>                         resource:        d
>                     };
>                 });
>
>             }).then(function() {
>                 $scope.gridApi.grid.modifyRows($scope.gridOptions.data);
>                 $scope.gridApi.core.refresh();
>             });
> ```

Note that I'm using Restangular with Rails4.  The trick is to complete the application to the data set in GridOptions, then call modifyRows() and refresh().

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
   $scope.gridOptions ={

   data : [],
   columnDef:[]

   };
 $scope.data=[];
 $scope.couumnDefs=[];

 myService.getData().then(function(data) {
                    var status = data.status;
                    if (status == 0) // success
                    {
                        $scope.data= data.gridData;
                       $scope.columnDef= data.gridCoulmunDef;
                    }
                }, function(errorMessage) {
                    $scope.error = errorMessage;
                });

 $scope.gridOptions.data=$scope.data;
 $scope.gridOptions.columnDef=$scope.couumnDefs;
```

Hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

update it like below and try

```
myService.getData().then(function(data) {
                    var status = data.status;
                    if (status == 0) // success
                    {
                        $scope.data= data.gridData;
                       $scope.columnDef= data.gridCoulmunDef;
                        $scope.gridOptions.data = $scope.data;
                       $scope.gridOptions.columnDef= $scope.columnDef;
                    }
                }, function(errorMessage) {
                    $scope.error = errorMessage;
                });
```

you need to assign coldef and data again aftercall of service.